How to allow non-admin users to change IP address on network adapter without adding them directly to the NCO group
Some users in the company require ability to change IP address on network adapters. (Engineering users need to directly connect their laptops to various machines that won't lease out address via DHCP).
We looked at the Network Configurations Operator group as the solution and it kind of works but not the way we need it. Due to restrictions imposed by Cyber Essentials cert requirements we can not add users directly to the NCO group. We can only create a secondary account that is a member of the group and then can be used for elevation in UAC prompt. This has been tested and worked fine on standalone and domain joined machine but when we tried to use it on the Azure AD joined device we ran into a problem. On Azure joined device somehow it is not possible to elevate with the secondary account unless it is admin.  Membership of Network Configuration Operators technically should be sufficient to access Network Adapter settings but it is not. I tried running the PS/CMD window as the secondary user and changing IP using netsh command but that complains about permissions as well.
It is still possible to change adapter settings if logged in directly to the secondary account but users are complaining that it takes too long to switch between accounts if they need to change the IP settings more than few times a day.
At this point I am not sure if this is a general thing for Azure joined machines or is one of our default config policies blocking that somehow.
I looked at 3rd party tools like NetSet man that once installed allows user to manage network settings without elevation but it is coming from a small developer and our security dept is concerned about patching, also it did go a bit buggy in testing.
We are potentially looking at whitelisting the action via ThreatLocker but this is still in deployment so may not be an option just now.
Has anyone run into that issue? Ideally I would want to get the secondary NCO account to work for elevation but any other suggestions that meet above restrictions will be appreciated.

If the machine is set to always get a DHCP IP address, you could consider letting them install a DHCP server so they manage their IP through that. Keep in mind that if they are connected to the normal network, their DHCP server could also start leases for other users. To combat this, you could give them a router where they connect to to get them an IP address, and connect other stuff they need to that router too. Another option, if this is purely for software development, is that they use a VM. Inside the VM software, they can setup the IP for their guest.

Also, if those machines don't move, consider placing routers near those machines, and setup DCHP so that if they connect their laptop to that router, they automatically get the IP address required for those machines.

Thank you, both solutions would work in principle but they would not be acceptable by our client. I am still at the stage where I am hoping to figure out why is it not possible to elevate IP change with separate account on Azure joined device when this works just fine on domain joined or standalone devices. I will do some more testing but hopefully someone run into this already.
